# Issues with Border in Custom Grid View in Wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am presently creating customGrid table,and problem that i presently face is border of the every cell,I am getting this dot like structure which reflects from background,Can i now how could it be recitified.

[image]

and code i used is

```
 GridLength len2 = new GridLength(value);
                    Column.Width = len2;
                    tableGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(Column);
                    TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();

                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        textBlock.Text = headers[j];
                        textBlock.FontSize = 35;
                        border = new Border();
                        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightGray);
                        border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                        textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        textBlock.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                        textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Data Value j is"+dataValues[j]);
                        textBlock.Text = "Content" + i + "/" + j;
                        //textBlock.Text = dataValues[j];
                        textBlock.FontSize = 25;
                        border = new Border();

                        textBlock.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
                        SolidColorBrush brush = GetColorFromHexa("0FFB0C4DE");/*0FFB0C4DE*/
                        border.Background = brush;

                        border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

                    }

                    Grid.SetRow(border, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(border, j);
                    tableGrid.Children.Add(border);
                    Grid.SetRow(textBlock, i);
                    Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, j);                            
                    tableGrid.Children.Add(textBlock);
```

any Property that needs to be changed to avoid that dot border in end of every cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the [Grid.ShowGridLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.showgridlines%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to be false:

tableGrid.ShowGridLines = false;